# Bootstrap navbar vertical divider

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having problems with adding a vertical divider in my navbar. The css I am using is sort of working but the vertical divider is only showing on the last link in the menu? I've searched here and found a solution in putting a border on the left which worked but doesn't look good at all on my menu. As you cans see from the image the divider is at the end, I am trying to get it showing on each link.
[image]

I am pretty pants when it comes to css and am sure I have the selector messed up.

Any pointers?

```
    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div class="row no-gutters shadow">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-1">
      <img src="<?php echo URLROOT.'/public/img/msplogo.jpg'; ?>" class="header-logo mx-auto d-block"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-11">
      <div class="row no-gutters h-50">
        <div class="d-none d-lg-block col-12">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-msp-darkblue h-100 py-0">
              <ul class="navbar-nav h-100 mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                  </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

/* Large viewport navbar */
.nav-link {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8vw;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  height:100%;
  padding-top:1.4vw;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #ff7240;
  color:#fff!important;
}

.nav-link:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: calc(50% - 1rem);
    right: 0;
    width: 1px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.15);
}
```

Comment: What would happen if you add `position:relative` to `.nav-link` ? And could you add a `z-index` to `.nav-link:before` ? 99999999 will do fine.

Comment: Adding position:relative worked :-) thanks! Do you know If i can use last-child to remove the last pipe?

Comment: Sure, don't know if they have to be in order per se though, but something like `.nav-link:last-child:before{display:none}` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might as formulate a complete answer:

Since the elements are built ltr, and absolute positioned elements are taken out of the flow of the document, the upcoming `<li>`s and its embedded `<a>` are effectively stacked on top of the previous `.nav-link:before`'s content; hence hiding it. The z-index (from the third dimension) solves this issue by bringing it to an higher layer.

The other issue lay with the last element of the children not being `.nav-link`, but being `.nav-item`. So the proper solution would be `.nav-item:last-child>.nav-link:before{display:none}`.

A final remark concerning the "no-pipe" solution; while this is actually preferred in comparison to linking, chaining and nesting in css for performance, it makes little sense to declare position, content, top, right, width, height en background for an element you don't want to display. Just `display:none` would have sufficed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ravb78 I have fixed my code by using position:relative in the nav-link. I wanted to remove the pipe at the end and I thought that I could use a last-child but that just removed the pipes at the font and left the one at the end like the pic. I think it has something to do with the hierarchy of the links????

Instead I just added a .no-pipe css to the last link.

```
/* Large viewport navbar */
.nav-link {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8vw;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  height:100%;
  padding-top:1.4vw;
}
/* adds the hover affect on the links */
.nav-link:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #ff7240;
  color:#fff!important;
}
/* adds the pipe to the links */
.nav-link:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: calc(50% - 0.9rem);
  right: 0;
  width: 1px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.15);
}
/* removes the pipe from the last link */
.no-pipe:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: calc(50% - 1rem);
  right: 0;
  width: 0px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.15);
}
```

Comment: yeah my bad, it should've been `.nav-item:last-child>.nav-link:before{display:none}`